# What is the function for each Python data structures?

Tags: python, data-structures

There are so many data structures in python. some times I thought some of them may be useless, the only needed is list. Any one can tell me what is the function of each python data structures?

Comment: Everyone of them is useful. Which ones do you think are unnecessary? Floats instead of ints? Lists instead of tuples or deque or array or set?

Comment: This is not a real question..

Comment: Oh great @Chris, now the universe will be replaced with something even more incomprehensible!

Comment: @Chris, you mean `[42]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the only needed is list

I assume you talk about collections, because lists without atomic values to put into lists are worthless. Still, there are lots of things lists don't work well for. Of course, if you never (or so rarely elegance and performance doesn't matter) need to [better choices in brackets]...

- Get a value by a key [dicts]
- Check for membership in a set [sets]
- Prevent duplicates [sets]
- Perform set operations (union, difference, etc.) [sets]
- Treat strings as text, not as collections of characters (e.g. title-case words) [string]
- Model trees [depends, but frequently hand-rolled]
- Model graphs (you wouldn't believe how incredibly general those are) [dicts or hand-rolled]
- Ensure immutability [tuple, frozenset, string]
- Remove and add items *at the beginning* [dequeue]
- Ensure FIFO (first in, first out) semantics [queue]

then you may get along with lists alone. And that's just the uses cases the standard library collection types cover that I know off the top of my head. There are many other data types, and many more ways to use each collection.

I don't know about you, but I'd estimate I don't even use lists for *half* of my collection needs. It depends on the project, of course, but few problems only require sequences.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean collection datatypes, then yes, everything *can* be done with lists. In fact, everything can be done with pairs (length-2 tuples). However, operations would be very slow and cumbersome to write.

For associations between keys and values with constant-time lookup, insert and delete, there's `dict`. For collections of non-repeated elements with constant-time lookup, insert and delete, there's `set`. The purpose of all other collections should be described in the Python documentation.

Pick up a good book on algorithms and data structures to get a grasp on the fundamental benefits and drawbacks of various collection structures.